Как с помощью python работать с консолью js?
У меня есть такой вот код на python, использую selenium. Мне надо получить вывод консоли js в браузере, как видно, я отправляю скрипт который выводит Hello, World! в консоль браузера. Как мне с помощью python получить то, что было выведено в консоли?
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
time.sleep(1)

code = "console.log('Hello, World!');"
driver.execute_script("console.clear();")
driver.execute_script(code)
time.sleep(1)

logs = driver.get_log("browser")
for log in logs:
    print(log["message"])


Я пытался найти библиотеки для решения проблемы, но не нашел. Использую python 3.10

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

# enable browser logging
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)

# load the desired webpage
driver.get('https://google.com')

# print messages
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print(entry)

Так вы сможете получить сообщения из консоли
